# Push Panels not working as they should

Tags: jquery, mobile, push, panels

i'm having a little problem. My push panels on this site are not running as they should.

Here is the link: http://www.glaserarbeiten.info/mobilewebsite/

Im pretty new to jquery mobile. I thought i could get some help here.

If you click the panel, and go to another page and activate the push panel there again and switch back to e.g. home the panel is not sliding out sometimes. I tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari + Samsung Galaxy SII standard browser.

Heres the code:

```
<!--search panel -->
    <panel>
    <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="push" data-position="right" data-theme="a">
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>
    </div>
    </panel>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <!--nav panel -->
    <panel>
    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="push" data-position="left" data-theme="a">
            <div class="main-navi">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#homesite" class="navi-link" data-lid="Home">home</a>
                <li><a href="#aussenstellen" class="navi-link" data-lid="aussenstellen">notfallreperatur</a>
                <li><a href="#contactform" class="navi-link" data-lid="termin">termin vereinbaren</a>
                <li><a href="#aussenstellen" class="navi-link" data-lid="ueber uns">Ueber uns</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </panel>
    <!-- /panel -->
```

Comment: First post has been edited.

Comment: Hi Guys,

found the Mistake, i called the same id, "left-panel" on the other data-pages.
So the js called all the id's on every single page, what could not work well :)

Answer (score 0):

found the Mistake, i called the same id, "left-panel" on the other data-pages.
So the js called all the id's on every single page, what could not work well :)